# Communication problems between a Tomcat client and the first ignite server

Tags: tomcat, communication, ignite

Occasionally, I have communication problems between clients and some server. In this case, between a tomcat client and the first server.

The following messages appear continuously in the server log:

```
INFO TcpCommunicationSpi:566 - Accepted incoming communication connection [locAddr=/10.153.0.55:48100, rmtAddr=/10.153.0.54:31419]
INFO TcpCommunicationSpi:566 - Received incoming connection from remote node while connecting to this node, rejecting [locNode=1c500cd0-0873-42be-8273-a955286d1914, locNodeOrder=1, rmtNode=660a2a91-eecc-477a-be6c-20b480ba8b42, rmtNodeOrder=93]
INFO TcpCommunicationSpi:566 - Accepted incoming communication connection [locAddr=/10.153.0.55:48100, rmtAddr=/10.153.0.54:31421]
INFO TcpCommunicationSpi:566 - Received incoming connection from remote node while connecting to this node, rejecting [locNode=1c500cd0-0873-42be-8273-a955286d1914, locNodeOrder=1, rmtNode=660a2a91-eecc-477a-be6c-20b480ba8b42, rmtNodeOrder=93]
INFO TcpCommunicationSpi:566 - Accepted incoming communication connection [locAddr=/10.153.0.55:48100, rmtAddr=/10.153.0.54:31423]
INFO TcpCommunicationSpi:566 - Received incoming connection from remote node while connecting to this node, rejecting [locNode=1c500cd0-0873-42be-8273-a955286d1914, locNodeOrder=1, rmtNode=660a2a91-eecc-477a-be6c-20b480ba8b42, rmtNodeOrder=93]
INFO TcpCommunicationSpi:566 - Accepted incoming communication connection [locAddr=/10.153.0.55:48100, rmtAddr=/10.153.0.54:31425]
INFO TcpCommunicationSpi:566 - Received incoming connection from remote node while connecting to this node, rejecting [locNode=1c500cd0-0873-42be-8273-a955286d1914, locNodeOrder=1, rmtNode=660a2a91-eecc-477a-be6c-20b480ba8b42, rmtNodeOrder=93]
INFO TcpCommunicationSpi:566 - Accepted incoming communication connection [locAddr=/10.153.0.55:48100, rmtAddr=/10.153.0.54:31427]
INFO TcpCommunicationSpi:566 - Received incoming connection from remote node while connecting to this node, rejecting [locNode=1c500cd0-0873-42be-8273-a955286d1914, locNodeOrder=1, rmtNode=660a2a91-eecc-477a-be6c-20b480ba8b42, rmtNodeOrder=93]
INFO TcpCommunicationSpi:566 - Accepted incoming communication connection [locAddr=/10.153.0.55:48100, rmtAddr=/10.153.0.54:31429]
INFO TcpCommunicationSpi:566 - Received incoming connection from remote node while connecting to this node, rejecting [locNode=1c500cd0-0873-42be-8273-a955286d1914, locNodeOrder=1, rmtNode=660a2a91-eecc-477a-be6c-20b480ba8b42, rmtNodeOrder=93]
INFO TcpCommunicationSpi:566 - Accepted incoming communication connection [locAddr=/10.153.0.55:48100, rmtAddr=/10.153.0.54:31431]
INFO TcpCommunicationSpi:566 - Received incoming connection from remote node while connecting to this node, rejecting [locNode=1c500cd0-0873-42be-8273-a955286d1914, locNodeOrder=1, rmtNode=660a2a91-eecc-477a-be6c-20b480ba8b42, rmtNodeOrder=93]
INFO TcpCommunicationSpi:566 - Accepted incoming communication connection [locAddr=/10.153.0.55:48100, rmtAddr=/10.153.0.54:31433]
INFO TcpCommunicationSpi:566 - Received incoming connection from remote node while connecting to this node, rejecting [locNode=1c500cd0-0873-42be-8273-a955286d1914, locNodeOrder=1, rmtNode=660a2a91-eecc-477a-be6c-20b480ba8b42, rmtNodeOrder=93]
INFO TcpCommunicationSpi:566 - Accepted incoming communication connection [locAddr=/10.153.0.55:48100, rmtAddr=/10.153.0.54:31435]
INFO TcpCommunicationSpi:566 - Received incoming connection from remote node while connecting to this node, rejecting [locNode=1c500cd0-0873-42be-8273-a955286d1914, locNodeOrder=1, rmtNode=660a2a91-eecc-477a-be6c-20b480ba8b42, rmtNodeOrder=93]
INFO TcpCommunicationSpi:566 - Accepted incoming communication connection [locAddr=/10.153.0.55:48100, rmtAddr=/10.153.0.54:31439]
INFO TcpCommunicationSpi:566 - Received incoming connection from remote node while connecting to this node, rejecting [locNode=1c500cd0-0873-42be-8273-a955286d1914, locNodeOrder=1, rmtNode=660a2a91-eecc-477a-be6c-20b480ba8b42, rmtNodeOrder=93]
INFO TcpCommunicationSpi:566 - Accepted incoming communication connection [locAddr=/10.153.0.55:48100, rmtAddr=/10.153.0.54:31441]
INFO TcpCommunicationSpi:566 - Received incoming connection from remote node while connecting to this node, rejecting [locNode=1c500cd0-0873-42be-8273-a955286d1914, locNodeOrder=1, rmtNode=660a2a91-eecc-477a-be6c-20b480ba8b42, rmtNodeOrder=93]
INFO TcpCommunicationSpi:566 - Accepted incoming communication connection [locAddr=/10.153.0.55:48100, rmtAddr=/10.153.0.54:31443]
INFO TcpCommunicationSpi:566 - Received incoming connection from remote node while connecting to this node, rejecting [locNode=1c500cd0-0873-42be-8273-a955286d1914, locNodeOrder=1, rmtNode=660a2a91-eecc-477a-be6c-20b480ba8b42, rmtNodeOrder=93]
INFO TcpCommunicationSpi:566 - Accepted incoming communication connection [locAddr=/10.153.0.55:48100, rmtAddr=/10.153.0.54:31445]
```

It was necessary to restart the tomcat so that everything would stabilize.
Would anyone know the reason for these mistakes? And if there is any way to make the system recover.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a chance that you are using a particularly old version of Ignite? There were several bugs fixed around 1.5 years ago which manifested like that.

Other than that, you can observe such errors when one host thinks connection is closed but other still considers it alive. Tweaking all kinds of timeouts may help (on `TcpCommunicationSpi`) as well as just making sure that connections don't close at random.